# Reconnect to Db2 Database in running spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, db2

I am connecting to a db2 database using springBoot application. Over weekend the connection to database gets lost, with a connection reset exception.
I need to have some auto retry mechanism in my application, where in when the request comes, and it gets a connection closed exception , the application  should reconnect back to database.
I am using SpringBoot 2.1.2 Release.
db2jcc4 version is 4.26.14
At the server startup the database connection is established.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="data.app")
@Bean
public DataSource dataSourceApp(){

return new HikariDataSource(new HikariConfig())
}

@Bean
EntityManagerFactory appEntityManagerFactory(){
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ();
emf.setDataSource(dataSourceApp);
emf.setJPAVendorAdaptor(jpaVendorAdaptor);
emf.afterPropertiesSet();
return emf.getObject();

}


@Bean
publc EntityManager appEntityManager()
{
return appEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}
```

Then this entityManager is used for executing queries for each request.

Following are the connection pool properties

```
data.app.minimumIdle=0
data.app.idleTimeout=120000
data.app.driverClassName=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
data.app.jdbcURL=
data.app.username=
data.app.password=
data.app.maximumPoolSize=10
data.app.connectionTimeout=300000
data.app.poolName=
data.app.maxLifetime=130000
data.app.validationTimeout=300000
```

I want to reconnect to this database, when the first request comes and it encounters connection close exception.
(Only want the Database bean to be reconnected , entire application should not be restarted ).

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Please edit your question to specify the exact version of the db2jcc4.jar file that you are using. Ensure db2jcc4.jar is on the CLASSPATH and run `java com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version`, which should tell you the exact version.

Comment: Hi, we are using db2jcc4 4.26.14 version. Thanks

Comment: One update to this.. I added the Hikari Cp JMX monitoring for active, idle and total connections. I found when the application starts the active connections are 0.once I execute the query, active connections increase to 1 and even if I execute the queries 40 times active connections remain at 1. After idleTimeout and maxlifetime also the active connections remain at 1. I am using entityManager.createNativeQuery() to create query Data and then executequery() to execute it. In the finally block I am closing entitymanager by entitymanager. Close(). How can I return the connection back to pool?

Answer (score 0):

Used the @RefreshScope of Spring actuator, and changed the following

```
@Bean
publc EntityManager appEntityManager()
{
return appEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}
```

to

```
@Bean
publc EntityManager appEntityManager()
{
return SharedEntityManagerCreator.createSharedEntityManager(appEntityManagerFactory);
}
```

On calling the refresh endpoints the database is relaoded. Using SharedEntityManagerCreator also returned the connection back to pool.